# Why Typescript doesn't fail when spreading a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, iterator

Having a typescript piece of code like the following:

```
const f = () => {}
const o = { ...f }
// o === {}
```

Why doesn't TS complain about spreading a function? I would expect this to be ok in plain javascript (since functions are objects in the end) but I don't understand why TS allows this (does it make any sense for a function to be iterable?)

Comment: at the end of the day a function is an object and the iterator is used for objects.

Comment: Functions are objects, and therefore have properties which can be spread into another object.

Comment: @DivineSoul no iterator is used here.

Comment: "*(does it make any sense for a function to be iterable?)*" you're not doing ANY ITERATION. Object spread is completely different and basically unrelated to array spread. Why *wouldn't* object spreading work here? `f = {a: 1, b: 2}` works, right? And you'd *expect* it to work, correct? Yet that object is not iterable, either.

Comment: Functions *may* have spreadable properties ([example](https://tsplay.dev/N71K4W)) but most of them don't.  The idea that TS should warn when spreading something with no *known* spreadable properties was brought up in [ms/TS#49161](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49161) but that's considered too restrictive, so that's why there's no error here.  Presumably this could be made into a linter rule, but it's not something that already exists as far as I know.

Comment: @VLAZ you have the 3 dots '...' which is an iterator. Doesn't matter if it's a object or array

Comment: @DivineSoul The term "iterator" is nonstandard for object spread; objects aren't generally [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#iterators).  While similar looking, the `[...x]` and `{...x}` syntaxes do different things; the former only works if `x` is iterable, while the latter works if `x` is spreadable

Comment: @DivineSoul no it's not. Objects do not implement iterable by default: https://jsbin.com/difajajivu/edit?js,console Object spread does not invoke an iterator. Unlike array spread. https://jsbin.com/picesozuga/1/edit?js,console Prove me wrong - show me where an iterator is invoked.